# iOS reloadTable function from another view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnotificationcenter

I've two view controller A and B.

Into A I have a UITableView and a NSNotification observer into viewDidLoad function.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(refreshInterface) name:@"newDataAreAvailable" object:nil];
```

The related selector:

```
-(void) refreshInterface{
    [[self tableView] reloadData];
}
```

Now, from my B ViewController I post a notification to A to reload my tableview data.

But `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is never called and `numberOfRowsInSection` return 5 elements.

Why?

Comment: Interesting, someone felt this is so obvious it needs downvoting, but couldn't be bothered to say why.  I'll upvote the question in the interest of balance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cellForRowAtIndexPath is only called when the cell becomes visible.  If table A is not visible, it won't happen until it becomes visible.

You also need to confirm that your notification is being fired and that the reload is happening.

Comment: Ok, right. So I must to invoke refreshInterface into viewWillAppear and use postNotification only to change my datasource into A view controller. Is it correct?

Comment: No, if this is the reason the cellForRow... isn't being called, it will happen automagically when the second view controller becomes visible.
I think it is triggered by the TableView's draw rect.